# prevent kendo ui grid popup editor from closing after validation errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am returning errors from server and catch it in kendo datasource error event.In this event I am trying to prevent close popup editor, but it works only first time, after clicking update second time, the window keeps closing all the time.

Here is some code;

```
    dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
    create: function (e) {  
                 // just posting server with ajax     
                 InsertCity("/city/insert", e.data, function (res) {
                            var grid = $("#gCity").data("kendoGrid");

                            if (res.success) {
                                grid.dataSource.data(res.data);
                            } else {
                                e.error("", "", res.error);
                                grid.cancelChanges();
                            }
                        })
     },
     error: function (e) {
                // after throwing error in transport/create, it comes here
                var grid = $("#gCity").data("kendoGrid");
                grid.one("dataBinding", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
                alert(e.errorThrown);
            },
     pageSize: 20,
     schema: {
            model: {
                id: "ID",
                fields: {
                    Name: { type: "string" }/*,
                    EndDate: { type: "date" },
                    CreateDate: { type: "date" }*/
                }
            }
     }
    });


    $("#gCity").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        height: 550,
        selectable: "single",
        filterable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        toolbar: [{ name: "new", text: "New" }],
        columns: [{ field: "Name", title: "Name" }],
        editable: {
            mode: "popup",
            confirmation: false,
            template: kendo.template($("#popup_editor").html())
        }
    });
```

I searched a lot but could not find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Try add this :

```
var onWindowEditClose = function (e) {
  debugger;
    if (preventCloseOnSave) {
        e.preventDefault();
        preventCloseOnSave = false;
    }
};
```

i got it from [here](https://dojo.telerik.com/UKobIzuN)